# Why I inject the same bean, but injected different class actually?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, dependency-injection, sap-commerce-cloud

**A.java**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/a")
public class A {
    @Resource(name = "foo")
    private Foo foo;
}
```

**B.java**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/b")
public class B {
    @Resource(name = "foo")
    private Foo foo;
}
```

**x-spring.xml**

```
<alias name="foo1" alias="foo"/>
<bean id="foo1" class="com.example.Foo1" scope="tenant">
```

**y-spring.xml**

```
<alias name="Foo2" alias="foo"/>
<bean id="foo2" class="com.example.Foo2" scope="tenant">
```

Foo1 derived from Foo2. Project using Hybris, scope is tenant(defined by Hybris).

As above, I inject **"foo"** into **Class A** and **Class B**, and **x-spring.xml**, **y-spring.xml** loaded one by one. But I found the bean injected are different, it's **Foo1** in **Class A**, and it's **Foo2** in **Class B**, I wonder why they are different, and how to align them to Foo1.

Comment: Alias replaced?

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that x-spring.xml and y-spring.xml are in two different contexts, most likely two separated web contexts from two different extensions.

If you want them to be accessible in both contexts declare the bean once in the core application context.

**Tenant scope is deprecated, use spring contexts or yrequest**